# How to generate a set of numbers

Tags: c, math

I have to generate the set `Z` of the first 100 integers that satisfy the equation `i = 2^a * 3^b`, with `a` and `b` being integers.

That is, `Z = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, ...}`

What algorithm could I use ? I'll need to implement it in C.

Comment: what are `a` and `b` here? I did not get your question.

Comment: Do you want to generate the first K integers which satisfy `i = 2^a * 3^b` with `a` and `b` being integers ?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No problem. However, this question would be better suited to [math.se] as it is a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: why down vote... this is an interesting problem. you can't do it with simple for loop. you need to think of how to generating it while maintaining the order.

Comment: Do you need 100 *smallest* numbers that satisfy the equation, or just any such numbers? Do you need them sorted?

Comment: @dlask the smallest, that's what I asked. I don't think they need to be sorted though, as `z` is a set.

Comment: @Quentin this is more than a math problem. because human beings care less ordering. it's quite practical actually.

Comment: OK. Apparently I was misunderstood. I need to generate the set z with equation i = 2^a * 3^b, where are b and are integers. However the set of numbers can be a hundred members long. This is how that problem was given to me. So, basically, we do not know initially the rest of numbers which can be generated with the equation above

Comment: @user1415536 if you are not asking for the smallest 100 ones, things can change a lot. it's better for you to figure out what you want before asking.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr (not dowvoting, btw) From what I gathered, finding algorithms to solve math problems is off-topic. I wouldn't risk my hand on that though, and I *am* interested in the answer.

Comment: @dlask what about now? I thought I missed something,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has no code to fix, they just want a solution to their problem.  See also 'Questions seeking debugging help' for meta information.

Comment: Allright. The problem is, I can't find a proper algorithm that would satisfy a tester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef unsigned long long int ull;

ull cmp(const void * a, const void * b) { return *(ull *)a  - *(ull *)b; } 

int main() {
    int i = 0, a, b;
    int A = 17, 
        B = 16;
    int MAX = A * B;
    ull z[MAX];
    for (b = 0; b < B; ++b) {
        for (a = 0; a < A; ++a) {
            if (i >= MAX) break;
            z[i++] = pow(2, a) * pow(3, b);
        }
    }
    qsort(z, MAX, sizeof(ull), cmp);
    printf("{ ");
    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        printf("%lld%c ", z[i], i < 99 ? ',' : 0);
    printf("}");
    return 0;
}
```

Output

> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24, 27, 32, 36, 48, 54, 64, 72, 81, 96, 108, 128, 144, 162, 192, 216, 243, 256, 288, 324, 384, 432, 486, 512, 576, 648, 729, 768, 864, 972, 1024, 1152, 1296, 1458, 1536, 1728, 1944, 2048, 2187, 2304, 2592, 2916, 3072, 3456, 3888, 4096, 4374, 4608, 5184, 5832, 6144, 6561, 6912, 7776, 8192, 8748, 9216, 10368, 11664, 12288, 13122, 13824, 15552, 16384, 17496, 18432, 19683, 20736, 23328, 24576, 26244, 27648, 31104, 32768, 34992, 36864, 39366, 41472, 46656, 49152, 52488, 55296, 59049, 62208, 65536, 69984, 73728, 78732, 82944, 93312 }

**EDIT**: Gives correct output now without overflow (see http://ideone.com/Rpbqms)

Comment: Your code doesn't generate the *first* 100 numbers. `128` is missing there, for example.

Comment: @dlask Indeed, fixed.

Comment: Not fixed at all. `1024` is missing now.

Comment: The problem is tougher than it looks :D

Comment: Not exactly, it's [one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program) in Python. So what's the C equivalent? ;-)

Comment: @dlask Updated again, thanks. Problem is tough and something is stil wrong. Trying at it

Comment: Close enough. Thank you for your help. P.s. May be I just need to sleep more an avoid to ask such a questions on public =) Thank you guys anyway for helping.

Comment: @user1415536 You just need to decide correct for loop termination conditions both on a and b, and it'll output correctly

Comment: @user1415536 Updated, now gives correct output, verified.

Comment: Finally your result is correct. Speaking about general solution, it would be nice to get rid of the [magic constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) `17` and `16`.

Comment: @dlask You are right, but try to increment or decrement any one of them, and you'll either get overflow or wrong answer. It was very difficult to reach to those values and settle down.

Answer (score 2):

too much brute force...

let me propose a `O(n*lg n)` time `O(n)` space algorithm to achieve these.

i am not gonna provide any real code, but a piece of self invented pseudocode.

the idea is to use min-heap to maintain ordering:

```
func first-n-of-that(limit)
    heap = min-heap()
    heap.insert 1
    results = []
    while results.length < limit
        to-add = heap.pop
        results.add to-add
        heap.insert 2 * to-add
        heap.insert 3 * to-add
    return results
```

the correctness is provable by deduction.

Comment: Upvote, your solution is very smart and it gives correct results. Moreover, your pseudocode can be transformed to Python almost without any modification. I can provide it to you if you like.

Comment: @dlask non-necessarily. op asks for c node. but i just don't want to provide full answer for his own work.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force in Python (I know that C code is required):

```
sorted(2**a*3**b for a in range(100) for b in range(100))[:100]
```

And the result is …

Comment: ... still computing ? :p

Comment: @Quentin The result is provided very quickly. I am just not going to show it here. ;-)